# Account could not be parsed as token account: pubkey Solana

Tags: solana, solana-cli

I have been able to create the tokens and the accounts associated to handle the tokens and I have more than enough solana to send the token. I am trying to send my token to my phantom chrome extension wallet and I get this error.

`Account could not be parsed as token account: pubkey=`

I've been following these tutorials

https://learn.figment.io/tutorials/sol-mint-token

https://moralis.io/how-to-create-a-solana-token-in-5-steps/

It all works until I want to transfer the token. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: can you shoe me the command u used for transfering the spl token acc to the moralis guid it shud look like this `spl-token transfer <token-identifier> <token-amount> <wallet-address> --fund-recipient`

Comment: The problem was the way I had funded my solana wallet and how I set it up on the dev net. I changed it to the real solana network I used `solana config set --url mainnet-beta` and then continued with the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both articles have a flaw when it comes time to share your token with others. To send the token you have to fund the creation of the token account of the address receiving the token. You can do this with the following command

```
spl-token transfer --fund-recipient --allow-unfunded-recipient <token address> <quantity> <sol address>
```

I recommend following this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=befUVytFC80 by Network Chuck